# Chef server 12 reconfiguration is not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, chef-infra

I'm trying to install a Chef server on an Ubuntu 14.04 box. I've downloaded the .deb file from the site and installed with `sudo dpkg -i chef-server-core_12.0.8-1_amd64.deb` but when I do `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` all goes well until it reaches the postgresql part:

```
Running handlers:
[2015-05-03T23:16:07-04:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2015-05-03T23:16:07-04:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-05-03T23:16:07-04:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 44 resources updated in 198.107797872 seconds
[2015-05-03T23:16:08-04:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: private-chef_pg_database[opscode-pgsql] (private-chef::postgresql line 127) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[create_database_opscode-pgsql] (/opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/private-chef/providers/pg_database.rb line 13) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of createdb --template template0 --encoding UTF-8 opscode-pgsql ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "opscode-pgsql" does not exist
---- End output of createdb --template template0 --encoding UTF-8 opscode-pgsql ----
Ran createdb --template template0 --encoding UTF-8 opscode-pgsql returned 1
```

Am I missing any step? [The installation instruction](https://docs.chef.io/server/install_server.html) does not say anything about any other middle task to perform.

Thank you very much for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Saw exact same error installing chef-server-core-12.0.8-1.el6.x86_64.rpm on RHEL6.6.  Had gone through every pre-req step listed at https://docs.chef.io/install_server_pre.html ... finally chalked it up to having multiple versions of Postgres on the system.

Attempted the same install and reconfigure command (chef-server-ctl reconfigure) on a system without Postgres installed and had success.

HTH.

Comment: This is the most probable cause. I just bumped into this. Had `9.4` installed, chef tried to move in with `9.2`, misunderstandings happened, I had to sleep on the couch.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your problem. The installation of chef server 12.0.8-1 worked fine on my kitchen/vagrant setup

## Example

```
├── Berksfile
├── .kitchen.yml
├── roles
    └── chef-server.json
```

### Berksfile

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

cookbook "chef-server"
```

### kitchen.yml

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04
    driver:
      network:
        - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.38.34"}]
      customize:
        memory: 4096

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - role[chef-server]
    attributes:
```

### roles/chef-server.json

```
{
  "name": "chef-server",
  "description": "Chef server",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[chef-server]"
  ]
}
```